# Asm ascii to binary conversion

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, ascii, intel

im trying to convert ascii input to binary code in variable. Program is working good while number of inputed char is even. Don't know why when its odd i've got the wrong result. If the number of input is odd i'm trying to convert it to 8 bit binary like if i got 1 its like 00000001 and put it first then just take 2 ascii chars for low and hight 4 bits. Can you help ?

```
SYSEXIT         = 1
SYSREAD         = 3
SYSWRITE        = 4
STDOUT          = 1
STDIN           = 0
EXIT_SUCCESS    = 0
SIZE            = 500

.align 32

.bss
.lcomm bufor, SIZE
.lcomm bufor2, SIZE

.text
.global _start ;

_start:
mov $SYSREAD, %eax
mov $STDIN, %ebx
mov $bufor, %ecx
mov $SIZE, %edx

int $0x80

sub $1, %eax #od liczby znaków odejmujemy znak entera
mov %eax, %edi  #przeniesienie liczby wczytanych znaków z eax
mov $0,%dx  # reszta z dzielenia
mov $2,%cx  #dzielnik
div %cx     # ax:=dx:ax / cx
mov $0, %esi
mov $0, %ecx
mov $0, %ebp

petla:
mov bufor(,%ecx,1),%al
inc %esi
cmp $'a',%al
jge male
cmp $'A',%al
jge duze
cmp $'0',%al
jge liczby
next:
cmp $1, %dx
je niep
mov %al,%bl
shl $4, %ebx
inc %ecx
cmp %edi,%ecx
je koniec
jmp petla
next2:
or %al,%bl
mov %bl, bufor2(,%ebp,1)
inc %ebp
inc %ecx
cmp %edi,%ecx
je koniec
mov $0,%esi
jmp petla


male:
sub $'a', %al
add $10, %al
cmp $1,%esi;
je next
jmp next2

duze:
sub $'A', %al
add $10, %al
cmp $1,%esi;
je next
jmp next2

liczby:
sub $'0', %al
cmp $1,%esi;
je next
jmp next2

niep:
mov %al, bufor2(,%ebp,1)
inc %ebp
cmp %edi,%ecx
je koniec
inc %ecx
mov $0,%esi
mov $0,%dx
jmp petla

koniec:

movl $SYSEXIT, %eax;            #wyjscie z programu
movl $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
int $0x80
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: I attached the code to prevent asking for it. This took me serveral hours with gdb to debug this bug still nothing. When i add this one odd 4 bit number like 8 bit and then i add another 8 bit to variable i dont know why it mess all up.

Comment: We are not going to be able to help you spot the bug in dozens of lines of uncommented assembler.  There must be one particular line where your code's behaviour no longer matches what you expect.  Use the debugger to identify that line.